# Why if-statement is not considering "OR(s)"

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm making a program that is supposed to count vowels. I made a char array and via if-statement I'm checking each element of it:

```
for( i=0 ; sent[i]!='\0' ; i++)
{ 
   if (sent[i] = ='A'||'a'||'E'||'e'||'I'||'i'||'O'||'o'||'u') 
        { vow++; 
        }
}
```

Now when I'm typing "My name is Arsal" on console, it is giving output "16 vowels" which is actually the number of all alphabetic characters along with spaces in above sentence. 
When I'm removing "OR(s)"

```
if (sent[i] = ='A' /*||'a'||'E'||'e'||'I'||'i'||'O'||'o'||'u' */) 
    { vow++; 
    }
```

the program is giving the correct output of "1" in above sentence.

This is the complete program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    int vow=0;
    char sent[100];

    printf("Enter sentence ;  \n");
    gets(sent);
    printf("\n");
    int i,j;            
    for(i=0 ; sent[i]!='\0';i++)
    {

        if (sent[i] == 'A'||'a'||'E' || 'e' || 'O' ||'o'||'I'||'i' ||'U' ||'u')
        {
            vow++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n No.of vowels = %d",vow);

    getch();
}
```

Please tell me the reason.

Comment: You are ORing together all the bitmaps of those char binaries into one and comparing that with sent[i].  That is not what you need.

Comment: Are you using `= =` with a space inside in your real program?

Comment: Nerver use `gets`, use `fgets`

Comment: See [Why `gets()` is too dangerous to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) for an explanation of [Ôrel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4605105/%c3%94rel)'s succinct and accurate but inscrutable [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716927/why-if-statement-is-not-considering-ors#comment55204536_33716927)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression:

```
sent[i] == 'A'||'a'||'E' || 'e' || 'O' ||'o'||'I'||'i' ||'U' ||'u'
```

will evaluate to non-zero (that is a true value) for every value of `i`.

What you seem to want is something like:

```
if (strchr("AEIOUaeiou", sent[i])) {
    ++vow;
}
```

Comment: You really ought to explain _how_ the expression is incorrect and show what the correct version would be. Teach him how to fish. Don't just give him a fish.

Answer (score 3):

The format of your "or"s are incorrect...

Instead of 
`if ( sent[i] == 'A' || 'a' || 'e'` .... etc 
It needs to be:
           `if ( sent[i] == 'A' || sent[i] == 'a' || sent[i] == 'e'` ... etc

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that **In C, all non-zero integers are considered as true and 0 is considered to be false**.

So, here:

```
sent[i] == 'A'||'a'||'E' || 'e' || 'O' ||'o'||'I'||'i' ||'U' ||'u'
```

`sent[i] == 'A'` will be checked first. It is a condition that compares `sent[i]` with `'A'` and returns 1 if they are equal and 0, if they aren't.

Now, the rest of the stuff (`'a'` , `'E'` etc) are just positive integers (See the ASCII table). And these evaluate to true as they are non-zero.

When at least one of the operands of `||` are true, the entire condition becomes true (See the truth table of Logical OR).

Hence, the body of the `if` gets executed whatsoever.

---

The fix for this is given in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lowerto` and a `switch` `case`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main()
{
    int vow=0 ;

    char sent[100];

    printf("Enter sentence ;  \n");
    fgets(sent, sizeof(sent), stdin);
    printf("\n");
    int i;            
    for(i=0 ; sent[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        switch (tolower(sent[i])) {
          case 'a':
          case 'e':
          case 'o':
          case 'i':
          case 'u':
            vow++;
        }

    }
    printf("\n No.of vowels = %d",vow);             

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(  )
{
  int vow = 0;

  char sent[100];

  printf( "Enter sentence ;  \n" );
  gets( sent );
  printf( "\n" );
  int i, j;
  char c;

  for ( i = 0; sent[i] != '\0'; i++ )
  {

    //    if (sent[i] == 'A'||'a'||'E' || 'e' || 'O' ||'o'||'I'||'i' ||'U' ||'u')

    c = toupper( sent[i] );
    if ( c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U' )
    {

      vow++;
      printf( "\n%c is vowel", sent[i] );
    }

  }
  printf( "\n No.of vowels = %d", vow );

  getch(  );
}
```